Dataflow Job Stuck at 1 Worker with Oracle to BigQuery Template
I'm experiencing issues with a Dataflow job using the Oracle to BigQuery template. The job processes small tables from my Oracle source without problems. However, when I process larger tables, the job scales from 1 to 2 workers, but then consistently drops back down to 1 worker and remains stuck. The job never completes.
Resource Metrics:
A key observation is that the Total Shuffle data processed metric remains consistently low (820B) throughout the job execution. This suggests a bottleneck before the shuffle phase.
Resource Metrics
Job Logs:
The job logs contain two recurring warnings:
Unable to delete temp files: "gs://<DATAFLOW_BUCKET>/temp/dax-tmp-2024-09-26_10_58_07-5294014235542251679-S07-0-a9efc72e9936fc90/tmp-a9efc72e9936fd1f@DAX.recordio." I granted the service account Storage Object Admin permissions to the GCS bucket, but the error persists.

S07:Read from JdbcIO/Create.Values/Impulse+Read from JdbcIO/Create.Values/MapElements/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous)+Read from JdbcIO/JdbcIO.ReadAll/ParDo(Read)/ParMultiDo(Read)+Read from JdbcIO/JdbcIO.ReadAll/JdbcIO.Reparallelize/Consume/ParDo(Anonymous)/ParMultiDo(Anonymous)+Read from JdbcIO/JdbcIO.ReadAll/JdbcIO.Reparallelize/View.AsIterable/MapElements/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous) failed. This error points to a problem during the read operation from the JDBC source.

Execution Details:
The execution details show a significant straggler on task F149.
Straggler
Worker Logs:
The worker logs show no errors or warnings, only memory usage information similar to this:

Memory is used/total/max = 228/427/2290 MB, GC last/max = 2.85/2.85 % (configured threshold: 50.00%), #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=false

This suggests there's no memory pressure on the workers.
I've tested the job with both minWorkers=1, maxWorkers=5 and minWorkers=5, maxWorkers=10 configurations. In both cases, the job consistently drops to 1 worker and gets stuck. This indicates the issue is not simply a matter of insufficient worker capacity.
Autoscaling Metrics
CPU Utilization Metrics
Memory Utilization Metrics
Job Graph
I performed the same operation on an even larger table a few days ago, and it worked correctly. The parameters are identical, yet it's failing now.

Can you try to set the  connectionTimeout parameter in your connection string?
